# How to count a specific value in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 10, 100, 1000,10000],'B': [1, 2, 3, 4,5]})
df

    A       B
0   1       1
1   10      2
2   100     3
3   1000    4
4   10000   5
```

I need get a count number from dataframe column A where its value >100,

I know following way works

```
df['A'][df['A']>100].count()
2
```

Is there a beautiful way or smart way? I don't think df['A'] need show 2 times to get this count. I have many data statistics need this, so wanna to learn a more simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you check based on boolean value

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 10, 100, 1000,10000],'B': [1, 2, 3, 4,5]})
print(df['A']>100)
print("count",(df['A']>100).sum())
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
count 2
```

Comment: I think I lack of some basic data logic here. Yes,  it is based on boolean value, so (df['A']>100).count() will get a total row count, but .sum can get the right number here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean series with [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and chain [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) to sum all the `True` values:

```
df['A'].gt(100).sum()
# 2
```

Or indeed:

```
(df['A'] > 100).sum()
```

Comment: Cool! I got both 2 ways now!

Answer (score 1):

select rows where column value meets your conditional:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 10, 100, 1000,10000],'B': [1, 2, 3, 4,5]})
new_data = data.loc[data['A'] > 100]
print(new_data)
print(len(new_data))
```

which will output:

```
     A  B
3   1000  4
4  10000  5
2
```